# Erro na instalação do Zeos no Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, zeos

Como resolver este error no delphi 7 instalado no windows 7?

> ZComponent.dpk : Invalid compiler directive: '$ENDIF'

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo ele **[link](http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=3429)** retirado do fórum do **ZeosLib**, no post do **debian8** ele disse que esta diretiva está realmente errada e que poderia remover sem problema.

o referido erro era neste unit:

```
[DCC Error] ZComponent.dpk(58): E1030 Invalid compiler directive: '$ENDIF'
[DCC Fatal Error] ZAbstractConnection.pas(64): F1026 File not found: 'ZDbcAdo.dcu'
```

Este erro já pode ter sido corrigido, talvez seja interessante baixar a nova versão estável neste outro **[link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/files/Zeos%20Database%20Objects/zeosdbo-7.1.3a-stable/)**